# OTA-Defect comments field value returns with HTML tag

Tags: vba, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I have written a macro to get the last comments of all open defects in HP ALM.It works fine most of the time but sometimes for few specific defects instead of fetching the defect comments, it gets some random HTML tag. I am already using "TDConnection.IgnoreHtmlFormat=true" but still facing issue. Kindly help.

Comment: in hp, comment is not a log field. Its just a simple text where on clicking add comment button, it puts text at the end. If you get comment from that field then you will get all the comments. You mentioned that you need just last comment.

Comment: Correct, I get the all the comments and put in Excel. Then I extract the last comment from it. The issue is sometimes I get random html tags instead of the actual comment.

Answer (score -1):

Retrieving the value from the description field using OTA statement `testitem.Field("TS_DESCRIPTION")`, we get the value along with the HTML tag.

EXAMPLE:
if description of testcase is “*description test1*”, the output of `testitem.Field("TS_DESCRIPTION")` is `<HTML><body> description test1</body></HTML>`

Comment: Please don't link to your content unless it's absolutely necessary for the answer. Also, don't use the answer box to ask the OP follow up questions.

Comment: This is irrelevant answer to this question.